# Convert page into Matrix style

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I wanted to convert my web pages into *The Matrix* style in Google Chrome for better reading in night mode. So, I thought of writing a Google Chrome extension. I started out with writing a script for same.

## Objective:

I want to achieve something like this.

Selecting body tag in every HTML page and then apply the following style properties-

```
background-color :black;
color : lime;
```

### My take:

Here is what I started out with programming, but it doesn't seem to work. Please point out my mistakes and if you can suggest something better please do so.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.color = "lime";
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.background-color = "black";
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p> Hello </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Where does that html come from? Is it part of your extension?

Comment: Its part of testing...

Comment: Js wants background - document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.background = "black";

Comment: Have you considered just using CSS to do this?

Comment: What's the question exactly?

Comment: @BeardFist- How can just CSS do this change
P.S. - I am doing this to develop a Google Chrome extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is executing before the body tag exists. You need to wrap that into a onload function or put it at the end of your web page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
      document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.color = "lime";
      document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.backgroundColor = "black";
    }
</script>
```

This will give the page a chance to load, the body tag will exist and will then allow styling to be changed via JavaScript.

Comment: Changed my code, the background color property should be camel case.